# How to have fewer calls to the database using Entitiy Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using 10+ (depending of use case) calls to database, just to populate dropdown lists in my view.

Like in the code shown here:

```
ViewBag.FK_Grupe_Predmeta_ID = new SelectList(db.Get_Grupe_Predmeta(userLanguageID).ToList(), "ID", "Naziv");
ViewBag.FK_Klasifikacione_Oznake_ID = new SelectList(db.Get_Klasifikacione_Oznake(userLanguageID).ToList(), "ID", "Naziv");
ViewBag.FK_Stranke_ID = new SelectList(db.Strankes.Where(s => s.Povjerljiv == true), "ID", "Naziv");
ViewBag.FK_Prioriteti_ID = new SelectList(db.Get_Prioriteti(userLanguageID).ToList(), "ID", "Naziv");
ViewBag.odjeljenja = new SelectList(db.Get_Odjeljenja(userLanguageID).OrderBy(x => x.Naziv).ToList(), "ID", "Naziv");
ViewBag.VrstePostupka = new SelectList(db.Vrsta_Postupkas.ToList(), "PK_Vrsta_Postupka_ID", "Naziv_Vrste_Postupka");
```

I call stored procedures and tables. But when I test with multiple users in same time, I get long loading time, sometimes in the minutes.

Can't find any way to make less calls and populate `ViewBag` in same time.
Does anyone know what is the best approach in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: If it's stable data, use caching.

Comment: @GertArnold it is quite dynamic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion rather than passing entire entity sets to the SelectList constructor would be to just send a projection of the fields needed. I'd probably avoid calling Stored Procedures unless absolutely necessary and let EF interact with the tables to build optimal queries.

```
var strankes = db.Stranks
    .Where(x => x.Povjerljiv)
    .Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Naziv });
ViewBag.FK_Stranke_ID = new SelectList(stranks, "ID", "Naziv");
```

For common lookups, you can project to a view model for the ID and Name(Naziv) and then consider caching those to session to avoid re-loading them every time the page loads. Your SelectList gets built from the cached view models rather than hitting the DB again.

Make sure your DbContext lifetime scope is set no longer than per-request. DbContexts that have been alive longer and tracking far more entities over time become a lot slower for retrieving and updating entities. The more it is tracking, the more cached entities it will be sifting through when you ask for something, then going to the DB to read more entities, then stitching those resulting entities against it's local cache. (for populating any related entities, etc.) For maximum performance when loading sets fast, consider a bounded context with a minimum of navigation properties between lookup entities (mapping just FK columns) and read via a locally scoped bounded DbContext.

Other performance pitfalls to watch out for are any places where entities might be serialized and sent to the view. Entities that have navigation properties to lookups etc. that get "touched" by a serializer can end up triggering lazy loading to load each related entity one level at a time. My recommendation is always to project entities down to ViewModels to send to the view to avoid traps like this. Due to the queries lazy load traps can generate they can look a lot like cases where lookup queries are being triggered. An SQL Profiler can be very helpful for spotting situations where a lot of queries are being generated unexpectedly as a page loads.